# Angular view not updating after $scope update

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

First off, I am not sure if this is even possible since I'm still new to angular. I have 2 arrays and 2 views and I want each view to be associated with 1 of the arrays. So on one page I have a view that lists all items in the array. When a user clicks on one of the items I have it push to the other array. I then want that second view to show only the items that were pushed into that second array.

This is my code for the app

```
scheduleApp.controller('ScheduleController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.myShifts = [];

    $http.get('data/ninjas.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.shifts = data;


    });




//Available shifts main functions

$scope.removeShift = function(shift){
    var removeShift = $scope.shifts.indexOf(shift);
    shift.available = false;

    $scope.myShifts.push(shift);


};
```

}]);

First view that works fine showing the original array

```
<div class="content">
<h1 style="text-align: center">Available Shifts</h1>
  <button id="order" ng-click="order = 'name'">Order by Name</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search a shift" />
  <div id="titles">
    <span id="details">Shift Details</span><span id="times">Shift  
   Timeses</span>
  </div>
  <ul id="ninja-list">
    <li ng-repeat="shift in shifts | orderBy: order | filter: search" 
    ng-show="shift.available">
      <img ng-src="{{shift.thumb}}" style="margin:-12px 10px 0 0; 
    width:50px" ng-show="shift.thumb"/>
      <h3>{{shift.name}} - {{shift.rate | currency}}/Hr</h3>
      <div class="remove" ng-click="removeShift(shift)">CLAIM</div>
      <span class="belt">{{shift.date}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form ng-submit="addShift()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="newshift.name"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="belt" ng-model="newshift.date"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="rate" ng-model="newshift.rate"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
  </form>
 <a href="" ng-click="removeAll()">Remove All</a>
 </div>
```

Second view which is virtually the same only filled in to list the second array.

```
 <div class="content">
 <h1 style="text-align: center">My Shifts</h1>
  <button id="order" ng-click="order = 'name'">Order by Name</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search a shift" />
  <div id="titles">
    <span id="details">Shift Details</span><span id="times">Shift 
  Times</span>
  </div>
  <ul id="ninja-list">
    <li ng-repeat="myShift in myShifts | orderBy: order | filter: search" >
      <img ng-src="{{myShift.thumb}}" style="margin:-12px 10px 0 0; 
     width:50px" ng-show="myShift.thumb"/>
      <h3>{{myShift.name}} - {{myShift.rate | currency}}/Hr</h3>
      <div class="remove" ng-click="removeShift(myShift)">CLAIM</div>
      <span class="belt">{{myShift.date}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form ng-submit="addShift()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" ng-model="newshift.name"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="belt" ng-model="newshift.date"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="rate" ng-model="newshift.rate"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
  </form>
 <a href="" ng-click="removeAll()">Remove All</a>
 </div>
```

So basically $shifts outputs everything fine in the first view. When i push a certain item into $myShifts I want that to show when i change the view to the second view but nothing is listing.

Comment: What is the value of `filter:search` on the second view - where your are using  `<li ng-repeat="myShift in myShifts | orderBy: order | filter: search" >` ?

Comment: Update: In the controller I made a string value "hey". I had it output at the top of both views. They both show "hey". I then made a function that will change the text to "bye" on click. (The click  event is only on view1). Once clicked in view one the text at the top changes to "bye" i then go back to view 2 and the text still say "hey". thats a simplified version of my problem.

Comment: Does the problem remain when changing `<li ng-repeat="myShift in myShifts | orderBy: order | filter: search" >` to `<li ng-repeat="myShift in myShifts" >`. If not,  Can you add a fiddle?